# apple-app-site-association universal link path format for wild card

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate, apple-app-site-association

Can I add the following wildcard to my apple-app-site-association file?

"trails*"

It is not specified here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

I would like to future proof it rather than having to add many paths in the future and I can't use ? as the char length may be different  e.g. trails-other, trails-info

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "xxx.app.xxx.yyy",
        "paths": ["trails/*", "trails-account/*", "trails*"]
      },
      {
        "appID": "xxx.app.xxx.xxx",
        "paths": ["*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever find out the answer to this? Curious as well

Comment: @peter unfortunately not.